# Draw curved lines,any suggestions

Tags: java, swing, geometry, draw, curve

Hello guys I need to draw the curved lines in bold mainly those starting N - S and if possible the ones getting 350-10 340-20 and so on. I have tried QuadCurve2D and drawArc, but none of those worked. Is there any way possible to avoid the use of drawPolyline(xPoints, yPoints, WIDTH) because it will take hundreds of pairs to draw just one line.

[image]

This is part of the code in order to avoid your loss of time testing yourself :

```
        public class PaintMyQuad extends JPanel {

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

        QuadCurve2D.Double curve = new QuadCurve2D.Double(200,0,200,100,200,200);
        QuadCurve2D.Double curve1 = new QuadCurve2D.Double(200,0,180,100,200,200);
        QuadCurve2D.Double curve2 = new QuadCurve2D.Double(200,0,160,100,200,200);
        //etc
        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2d.draw(curve);
        g2d.draw(curve1);
        g2d.draw(curve2);
        g2d.drawOval(100,100,200,200);
        g2d.drawArc(100,100, 100, 200, 90, 180);
        g2d.drawArc(100, 100, 100, 200, 180, 360);
        g2d.drawArc(100, 100, 0, 200, 90, 180);
        g2d.drawRect(100, 100, 200, 200);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure if this is an really an answer - but have I have run into a resolution problem. I have tried anti-aliasing but it looked worse. 
One way you could do it is in the for loop put an if statement for odd and even numbers.Happy for some advice on this, I was thinking there maybe a better library to get nicer circles.
Maybe I'm doing it the old school way?

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Stereonet{

  private static int centreX, centreY, radius;
  private Color colour;

  /**Stereonet template contructor takes 3 int parameters 
    * x, y for centre position and radius for stereonet radius*/
  public Stereonet(int x , int y, int radius, Color colour){

    centreX = x;
    centreY = y;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.colour = colour;

  }

    public void draw(Graphics g){

      Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;           
      g2D.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2F));  
      g.setColor(colour);
      g.drawOval(centreX - radius , centreY - radius, radius * 2 , radius * 2);
      g2D.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1F)); 
      g.drawLine(centreX, centreY - radius, centreX, centreX + radius);
      g.drawLine(centreX - radius, centreY, centreX + radius, centreY);

      g2D.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1F));

      for(int degrees = 10; degrees <= 80; degrees += 10){


        double greatRadius = radius / (Math.cos(Math.toRadians(degrees))); // radius of great circle
        int greatX1 = (int)Math.round(centreX + radius * (Math.tan(Math.toRadians(degrees))) 
                                        - greatRadius); // x coord of great circle left hemisphere
        int greatX2 = (int)Math.round(centreX - (radius * (Math.tan(Math.toRadians(degrees)))) 
                                        - greatRadius); // x coord of great circle right hemisphere
        int greatY = (int)Math.round(centreY - greatRadius); // y coord of great circle

        double smallRadius = (radius / (Math.tan(Math.toRadians(degrees))));
        int smallY1 = (int)Math.round((centreY  - (radius / (Math.sin(Math.toRadians(degrees)))) - smallRadius));
        int smallY2 = (int)Math.round((centreY  + (radius / (Math.sin(Math.toRadians(degrees)))) - smallRadius));
        int smallX = (int)Math.round(centreX - smallRadius);

        g.drawArc(greatX1, greatY, 2 * (int)Math.round(greatRadius), 2 * (int)Math.round(greatRadius), 
                  90 + degrees, 180 - ( 2 * degrees));
        g.drawArc(greatX2, greatY, 2 * (int)Math.round(greatRadius), 2 * (int)Math.round(greatRadius), 
                  270 + degrees, 180 - ( 2 * degrees));
        g.drawArc(smallX, smallY1, 2 * (int)Math.round(smallRadius), 2 * (int)Math.round(smallRadius), 
                  270 - degrees, 180 - ( 2 * (90 - degrees)));
        g.drawArc(smallX, smallY2, 2 * (int)Math.round(smallRadius), 2 * (int)Math.round(smallRadius), 
                  90 - degrees, 180 - ( 2 * (90 - degrees)));  

      }

    }

    public static int getRadius(){

      return radius;

    }  

    public static int getX(){

      return centreX;

    }  

     public static int getY(){

      return centreY;

    }
```

Comment: Sorry that it took me so long, i recently opened this project once more to complete it this time. I didn't understand at that time why you referred anti-aliasing, but now i get it. It seems that using RenderingHints is the only way to fix this. I am currently trying to apply Bicubic Interpolation but with no success. Did you make any progress? Also i got problem with the poles i am trying to apply Gaussian weighting quantification from an algorithm that i found online with no success (i am using this in order to "cluster" my poles in to groups).

Answer (score 2):

If you need bold lines, try so:

```
....
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;

BasicStroke pen1 = new BasicStroke(5); // this is stroke with 5px width,
g2d.setStroke(pen1);

g2d.drawArc(100,100, 100, 200, 90, 180);
g2d.drawArc(100, 100, 100, 200, 180, 360);
...
```

Make 2 strokes for two types of lines, and use it.

Comment: i need to draw the bold lines of the picture posted from the beggining as if you have an empty panel i refered to "bold" in order to let people know which lines i meant but thank you cause it ll have to be in bold when i finally draw them. Sorry if my english were not too good and mislead you.